# jQuery Email Validation script to Disable Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, validation

This is my script. But it doesn't seem to be working. It's not disabling the buttons or preventing form submission.

```
<script>
$("#fes-email").on("change", function() {

    if ($("#fes-email").length > 0) {

        $("#fes-email").attr("disabled", "disabled");

    } else {

        $("#fes-email").keyup(function(){

            var email = $("#fes-email").val();

            if(email != 0)
            {
                if(isValidEmailAddress(email))
                {
                    $("#fes-submit").attr("enabled", "enabled");

                } else {
                    $("#fes-submit").attr("disabled", "disabled");  
                }
            }
        });
    }
});

function isValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) {
    var pattern = new RegExp(/^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/i);
    return pattern.test(emailAddress);
}
</script>
```

My HTML:

```
<input type='email' id="fes-email" name='fes-email' class='fes-input animate' value='' placeholder='E-mail'>
        <input type='submit' id='fes-submit' class='fes-submit animate' value='>'>
```

Not sure what the problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like

```
$("#fes-email").on("change keyup", function () {
    var email = $(this).val();
    $("#fes-submit").prop("disabled", email.length == 0 || !isValidEmailAddress(email));
});

function isValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) {
    var pattern = new RegExp(/^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/i);
    return pattern.test(emailAddress);
}
```

Demo

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $("#fes-email").on("change keyup", function() {
    var email = $(this).val();
    $("#fes-submit").prop("disabled", email.length == 0 || !isValidEmailAddress(email));
  });

  function isValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) {
    var pattern = new RegExp(/^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/i);
    return pattern.test(emailAddress);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='email' id="fes-email" name='fes-email' class='fes-input animate' value='' placeholder='E-mail' />
<input type='submit' id='fes-submit' class='fes-submit animate' value='>' />
```

Comment: Works great here. But can't seem to get it working when I add it to my code. Could something be interfering?

Comment: @Boris There could be multiple reasons... are you sure the event handler is getting called.. add a `alert` or `console.log()` statement before `var email = $(this).val();` to see whether the function is getting called

Comment: @Boris can you alert the value of `$("#fes-submit").length` and `$("#fes-submit").prop('disabled')` after the line `$("#fes-submit").prop("disabled", email.length == 0 || !isValidEmailAddress(email));`

Comment: Sometimes it works. Sometimes it doesn't. When I do enter some text, it goes disabled. But when the page is freshly loaded, you can click it. Do I disable it with html? Also, the form ends up getting submitted when I press enter, even if the button is disabled.

Comment: @Boris you will have to do the same validation in the form submit handler also... another solution is to make the button as disabled on page load(it won't work if the email comes prefilled in some cases)...

Comment: Not entirely sure how to do that, can I get some help?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70085/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-boris).

Comment: I've attempted to show and hide a div. Hide it when the email is valid. And show it when it's not. I tried toggle. But can't seem to incorporate it in the code you provided above. Can I get a hint as to how I can accomplish this?

Comment: This is what I have: But it doesn't hide the div. `$("#fes-email").on("change.validation keyup.validation", function () {
     var email = $(this).val(); 
   $("#fes-submit").prop("disabled", email.length == 0 || !isValidEmailAddress(email));
 }).trigger('change.validation');

 $('#fes-form').submit(function () { 
     var isValid = !$("#fes-submit").is(':disabled');
      $("#notification-container").slideToggle(!isValid);
    return isValid;
 });`

Comment: thank you! One more question. I have two different layouts using media tag. The slide up animation works perfectly for the fist layout. But doesn't for the second layout. Is it possible to change the animation depending on the width of the page?

Comment: can I use something like this? `function checkPosition() {
    if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 800px)').matches) {
        // slide animation
    } else {
        // fade animation
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

change `if ($("#txtEvent").length > 0)` 
to

```
if ($("#txtEvent").val().length > 0)
```

and see if the button is disabled

Comment: remove value='' from your html please